# How do I exclude a command in python if it is NoneType?

Tags: python

I have the error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute
```

so I added an if to prevent the following line from being executed:

```
if library.info != NoneType:
    library.info.update(info)
```

but that doesent work, I get the error that `NoneType` is not valid somehow

how do I write suche an if?

Answer (score 2):

Compare directly against its value:

```
if library.info is not None:
    library.info.update(info)
```

Answer (score 1):

Python does not have any built-ins by the name of `NoneType` (however, Python 2.x *does* have a [`types.NoneType`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/types.html#types.NoneType)).

Instead, Python uses `None` to represent a nonetype.  So, your code should be this.

```
# You should always use `is` and `is not` to test for `None`.
if library.info is not None:
    library.info.update(info)
```

Comment: I think the first sentence in the current edit could be a bit confusing, since there *is* `types.NoneType`. (+1 BTW)

Comment: @NPE - I meant built-ins as in the built-in functions, errors, etc.  However, I'll clarify.

Answer (score 1):

You could just say:

```
if library.info:
    library.info.update(info)
```

Looks clean

Comment: In some circumstances this could be incorrect (for example, what if `library.info` is an empty dict?) I would definitely recommend using `library.info is not None` instead.

Comment: Fair, I guess it would be up to the OP whether or not it's a safe decision to make. But if it were, I personally would do it

Answer (score 1):

Depending upon how often you expect `library.info` to be `None`, you might prefer an exception:

```
try:
    library.info.update(info)
except AttributeError:
    library.initialize_the_info_hoozit()
    library.info.update(info)
```